# Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub drp_usertype_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles drp_usertype.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

getting error under drp_usertype.SelectedINdexChanged

Its a dropdownlist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you declare the `drp_usertype` object it must be done as :

```
Private WithEvents drp_usertype As DropDownList
```

This is the same for

```
Private WithEvents drp_usertype As New DropDownList
```

etc...

The `WithEvents` keyword allows the control to hook up events, using the `Handles` syntax, with its owner.  When adding components in the designer it automatically generates this for you but when creating them yourself you must include the `WithEvents` if you intend to use events with the component.

If you do not declare an object `WithEvents` then handlers must be assigned programmatically as they are in C# using `AddHandler` -- see : [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This error would also thrown if there were no control defined with the name "drp_usertype".

I ran into this by copying functionality from one page to another and forgetting to rename the control after the "handles" key word.

Obviously, this wasn't your issue but I thought I'd post it for the benefit of anyone else who gets this error.